# Difference between pydoc and help()?

Tags: python, pydoc

Are these two things different? The results that the two give in Python are similar.

Answer (score 4):

`help()` is a Python function.

`pydoc` is a command-line interface to the same thing.

If you want to see more what pydoc does, take a look in pydoc.py (`import pydoc; pydoc.__file__`) and see what's in the `cli` function. It does do some extra importing magic, but I don't think it really needs to - `help()` accepts a string which is evaluated in the same sort of way, so if you have "foo.py", run `python` and do `help('foo')` it'll get just about the same result as `import foo; help(foo)` would, just with minor differences in layout, I think. Probably historical reasons there.

In short, `pydoc foo` is about equal to `python -c "help('foo')"`

Answer (score 3):

The interactive `help` function just imports pydoc.  From the source:

```
class _Helper(object):                                 
    """Define the builtin 'help'.                      
    This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).

    """                                                

    def __repr__(self):                                
        return "Type help() for interactive help, " \  
               "or help(object) for help about object."
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):                 
        import pydoc                                   
        return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)
```

Note the `__call__` definition.

You can see the documentation with `help(help)` ;-)

You can use the `inspect` module to check out the source yourself next time you're curious.

In case you want to investigate on your own, the following will return the source code definition of the module defined for an object:

```
inspect.getsource(inspect.getmodule(help))
```

Comment: Running `pydoc` on the command line lets you run a local http server, gui interface for starting/stopping the server, as well as a full suite of other features.  I have a git gist illustrating how to install `pydoc` in your local directory on [my blog](http://mvv.io/posts/6).

Answer (score 0):

In simple words I think `pydocs` can be explained as **Tesla, Inc.** and `help` is just a product of tesla like **Tesla Model S**

If one goes inside the `help` function code it is clearly mentioned that help is using `pydocs.help`

```
"""
Define the built-in 'help'.
    This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).
"""
```

`pydocs` has got many more options and features as compared to `help`